# Format input number into currency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've an amount input field (html element).

I need to format the value enter as D.DD since it represents money.

For example, If the initial value is 0.00 and user enters some amount, it should be entered as 10.00 on user key press? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? The way your current question is stated, you're going for a downvote fest

Comment: The reason for the rapid negative response is that this sounds like a "Do this piece of work for me". Try instead something like `I need X, I've tried Y and Z but they don't work because...`

Comment: I found my solution, At least you had to gave a chance to show you what I have tried. Here is what I had been trying http://jsfiddle.net/6wG26/5/ . You people blindly down voted. Thanks for that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/7JfbW/2/)**

Try this

```
$('#number').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which <= 46 || event.which > 59) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
$('#number').bind('blur', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0)
  $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));

});
```

and html

```
<input type="text" id="number" />
```

Comment: I had been trying some similar approach http://jsfiddle.net/6wG26/5/ .Thank you very much.